# How I can apply css to part of my jQuery result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I only need my day font size to be bigger than realMonth. how can I do that ? for instance my realMonth is Normal size, but I want my day to be Bold and 30px! is it possible?

```
$("#display").html(day +"<br/>"+realMonth);
         });
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `<span>` like this

```
$("#display").html("<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px'>" + day +"</span><br/>"+realMonth);});
```